# How to mint multiple NFT assets in the same transaction?

Tags: nft, native-assets, metadata, minting, developers

The developer guide doesn't cover this.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/e1c7bc707e56bf37b4325dc4b7fe524eafe8ca746e54746d60b321588ffebb6c?tab=tokenmint

I tried making the metadata look identical in structure but cardanoscan says my transaction only minted 1 coin.

I want my mint transaction to have multiple asset names.

Answer (score 6):

The process is the same but you need to specify in your `cardano-cli transaction build` command, all your assets to mint. For example:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
  --fee 197797 \
  --tx-in 6af4fea10fe3fd7120ab7e3f5361ae15d898f4fa6ebddcf585a80865010722dd#0 \
  --tx-out $(cat key1/payment.addr)+15850022+"1 $(cat policy.id).nft1"+"1 $(cat policy.id).nft2" \
  --mint="1 $(cat policy.id).nft1"+"1 $(cat policy.id).nft2" \
  --minting-script-file policy.json \
  --metadata-json-file metadata.json \
  --invalid-hereafter=41797828 \
  --out-file transaction.raw
```

And of course, modify your metadata to have all your assets.

**UPDATE**
Consider that from `cardano-cli` v 1.31, your asset names should be  [base16-encoded](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4635/1231), this is only for the `build-raw` command.

Your `metadata.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "721": {
        "1573568cde0f3c340266e50f0d108795f5e4190de939081f15287a24": {
            "nft1": {
                "name": "nft#00001",
                "image": "ipfs://QmfVzQceRW7Awo1t82CrzdLeoLddQqz4SB3kNC2wiWyGAs",
                "mediaType": "image/gif",
                "description": "My TEST NFT 00001",
                "propety1": "Serie 1",
                "propety2": "Red"
            },
            "nft2": {
                "name": "nft#00002",
                "image": "ipfs://QmfVzQceRW7Awo1t82CrzdLeoLddQqz4SB3kNC2wiWyGEs",
                "mediaType": "image/gif",
                "description": "My TEST NFT 00002",
                "propety1": "Serie 1",
                "propety2": "Black"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include here an example of what metadata.json might look like for multiple nfts?

Comment: Done, check my updated answer.