# Errror cardano-cli build-raw: AssetName deserisalisation failed expecting hexadecimal digit

Tags: cardano-cli, build

I am trying to figure out what's wrong but I do not see it, is my command really wrong? do I need to encode the token name with something? Get a different cardano-cli executable?

`transaction build-raw --tx-in c4d3606f4f9a3688d13aa1afbd114cd0e78cc04dc2c0952557db0fb4260d2560#0 --tx-out addr_test1qqrsm4vj985epelhc8qpv8jahaqpjll7ed67647dk47ku4x5x8xk48yntkwhc2s20manmqartkchrp2qxgfwdaezsq5qu9urvd+2000000+"1 b75d4e90a96db2468d4c3d45d65b1f846307b1fc25acdb5489851481.CSCT" --tx-out addr_test1vpl22c6vml7p7n5vv4n2mjf6sfw9kcse5c7jjk3uxc9dllcvvvj8q+2830000 --mint="1 b75d4e90a96db2468d4c3d45d65b1f846307b1fc25acdb5489851481.CSCT" --mint-script-file newtesttokenpolicy.script --invalid-hereafter 42970622 --fee 170000 --out-file c4d3606f4f9a3688d13aa1afbd114cd0e78cc04dc2c0952557db0fb4260d2560.mint.raw`

This builds tx with cli from mainnet Daedalus on Windows, but fails on my Ubuntu testnet with the latest cardano-node build. I have this error:

`option --tx-out:  unexpected "S" expecting hexadecimal digit AssetName deserisalisation failed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because since `cardano-node` v1.31, you should pass the asset name as base16-encoded.

You can use this command:

`echo -n "myassetname" | xxd -ps`