# Build transaction script ERROR in cardano .Not support the policyid with tokenname

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, blockchain

**this is my transaction build script**

> cardano-cli transaction build 
> --mainnet 
> --alonzo-era 
> --tx-in $txhash#$txix 
> --tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname" 
> --change-address $address 
> --mint="$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname" 
> --minting-script-file $script 
> --metadata-json-file metadata.json  
> --invalid-hereafter $slotnumber 
> --witness-override 2 
> --out-file matx.raw

**And i get this error when i add tokenname with policy id**
**if i remove the tokenname then its working fine.and also not showing tokenname in cardanoscan**

> option --tx-out:
> unexpected 'N'
> expecting alphanumeric asset name, white space, "+" or end of input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `cardano-cli` v1.31?

If so, please refer to [Errror cardano-cli build-raw: AssetName deserisalisation failed expecting hexadecimal digit](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/errror-cardano-cli-build-raw-assetname-deserisalisation-failed-expecting-hexade)

Answer (score 0):

This line is problematic:

> --tx-out $address+$output+"$tokenamount $policyid.$tokenname"

One your variables is not set. To try it out, just put `echo`  in front of the command to print out what the command really is with variables filled in.

Comment: --tx-out addr_test1vzzql63nddp8qdgka578hx6pats290js9kmn4uay5we9fwsgza0z3+1400000+1 71421b480f31fd04905d50d0fa5026a459f545acf78ba3f359cc053b.NFT1

Comment: above is the echo result of tx-out