# Is posible to do Batch minting of NFT with each NFT having different image?

Tags: nft, metadata, minting

Since the metadata is attached to a Tx not to the NFT, and is unique per transaction, there can not be such a thing as a Batch minting of NFT with each one having different metadata for example "image", is it?

I need to mint like 10 000ks NFTs, so i think my NFTs will all share same,  image, and all i can change is the name and policy for doing them unique NFTs. Am I right?

EDIT: In fact it is not possible even that they satisfy  the 721-Standar https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can mint multiple NFTs using different metadata, all this in the same transaction. Here is an example of how you should structure your [metadata](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/e1c7bc707e56bf37b4325dc4b7fe524eafe8ca746e54746d60b321588ffebb6c?tab=metadata)

Take a look on this: [How to mint multiple NFT assets in the same transaction?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4427/how-to-mint-multiple-nft-assets-in-the-same-transaction)

But you have the restriction of the max transaction size, you can't go over that limit. Depending of your metadata, you'll be able to mint 35-45 NFTs in the same transaction.

Comment: Will this structure of metadata show specifically for every asset the image in the web wallets?

Comment: Yes, because the image displayed is based on the token name and the token name is defined in your metadata.