# How to create a large one time NFT minting

Tags: plutus, nft

I want to mint a NFT collection in one transaction to reduce the cost in transaction fees and time how do I create a CIP-25 compliant one time minting policy? Are there any tutorials out there?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify all the minted items one by one and make a metadata such that all NFTs share the same policy this has been answered before:

[How to mint multiple NFT assets in the same transaction?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4427/how-to-mint-multiple-nft-assets-in-the-same-transaction).

Consider the fact that there is maximum size for a transaction, so you can mint between 25 to 30 maybe 35.